# How does golang app talk to postgres using docker in aws servers?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, docker, go

I have a docker instance like this

```
docker run --name my-db-name -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d postgres:latest
```

running in a server

And I have my golang app wrapped by docker running in the same server

```
func main() {
    db, _ := sql.Open("postgres", "postgres://postgres:@192.168.99.100:5432/postgres?sslmode=disable")

    http.HandleFunc("/test", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

The above is not working because the ip is not correct.

Since I am using mac, I need to use docker machine ip to connect to the docker postgres db, but in aws I don't

What is a good way to configure this?

Comment: In Docker you can set up (virtual, for the lack of a better word) networks, which come with an DNS server. After which you can use `my-db-name` to access Postgres. Read [the according docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/), then ask on http://superuser.com in case you have questions left.

Comment: There is also the [legacy link feature](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/) (but it might get deprecated soon, who knows) which is handy for such cases.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to configure different environments for your local development and for AWS?

If so, you could use environment variables like this:

```
env := os.Getenv("GO_ENV")
dbIP := "DOCKER_MACHINE_IP"
if env == "production" {
    dbIP = "AWS_POSTGRES_IP"
}
```

And simply provide the `GO_ENV` environment variable set to `production` to your docker container on AWS.